# Nginx location which rewrites and serves a file from different root

Tags: nginx

Stuck with an nginx config block.
I want to remove the /holding_page_error part of the request and then attempt to serve a file back from the remaining path requested (which will match a file directly).

I also want this to be the last rule applied to this request as I have other location blocks which will pick this up and cause further errors.

```
location /holding_page_error {
    root /usr/share/nginx/maintenance;
    rewrite ^/holding_page_error/(.*)$ /$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite...last` will commence the search for another `location` block to match the rewritten URI. Perhaps you meant to use a `rewrite...break`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

```
location /holding_page_error {
    root /usr/share/nginx/maintenance;
    rewrite ^/holding_page_error/(.*)$ /$1 break;
}
```

Which is similar to this:

```
location /holding_page_error {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/maintenance;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.